# JavaScript sub object is not accessible

Tags: javascript, object

I am new to object handling in JavaScript and I got stuck on a problem. I hope you can help me.

To understand what I am doing here: I have a multilevel object with two different phone numbers (short codes) for each country. Since the list got too long, I added a category for "Europe". When I try to access the data of the sub object, my reference is always undefined but my console.log(l2) is stating that the sub is there and should have the defined properties.

Can you help me to understand why the properties are undefined or what I am doing wrong?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qsov54an/

JS:

```
langs = {
    "CRA": {flag: '',cs:'4262',as:''},
    "Reviews": {flag: '',cs:'72074301',as:''},
    "Europe": {
        "Bulgarian": {flag: 'bg',cs:'4668',as:''},
        "Croatian": {flag: 'hr',cs:'4671',as:'4707'},
        "Czech": {flag: 'cz',cs:'4365',as:'4553'},
        "Danish": {flag: 'dk',cs:'4357',as:'4526'},
        "Dutch": {flag: 'nl',cs:'4343',as:'4511'},
        "English": {flag: 'gb',cs:'4164',as:'4482'},
        "Finnish": {flag: 'fi',cs:'4092',as:''},
        "Flemish": {flag: 'be',cs:'4500',as:''},
        "French": {flag: 'fr',cs:'4344',as:'4781'},
        "German": {flag: 'de',cs:'4345',as:'4473'},
        "Hungarian": {flag: 'hu',cs:'4221',as:'4729'},
        "Italian": {flag: 'it',cs:'4348',as:'4485'},
        "Latvian": {flag: 'lv',cs:'4674',as:''},
        "Lithuanian": {flag: 'lt',cs:'4673',as:''},
        "Norwegian": {flag: 'no',cs:'4356',as:'4533'},
        "Polish": {flag: 'pl',cs:'4351',as:'4512'},
        "Spanish": {flag: 'es',cs:'4346',as:'4524'},
        "Swedish": {flag: 'se',cs:'4349',as:'4554'},
        "Portuguese (PT)": {flag: 'pt',cs:'4347',as:'4522'},
        "Romanian": {flag: 'ro',cs:'4675',as:''},
        "Turkish": {flag: 'tr',cs:'4355',as:'4530'},
    },
    "Cantonese": {flag: 'cn',cs:'',as:''},
    "Chinese": {flag: 'cn',cs:'4353',as:'4752'},
    "English": {flag: 'us',cs:'4164',as:'4482'},
    "Estonian": {flag: 'ee',cs:'4669',as:''},
    "Hebrew": {flag: 'il',cs:'4670',as:'4727'},
    "Icelanding": {flag: 'is',cs:'4672',as:''},
    "Indonesia": {flag: 'id',cs:'4368',as:'4713'},
    "Japanese": {flag: 'jp',cs:'4265',as:'4717'},
    "Korean": {flag: 'kp',cs:'4366',as:''},
    "Malay": {flag: 'ms',cs:'4367',as:''},
    "Portuguese (BR)": {flag: 'br',cs:'4552',as:'4781'},
    "Russian": {flag: 'ru',cs:'4350',as:'4559'},
    "Serbian": {flag: 'rs',cs:'4677',as:''},
    "Slovenian": {flag: 'si',cs:'4676',as:''},
    "Tagalog": {flag: '',cs:'4678',as:''},
    "Thai": {flag: 'th',cs:'4354',as:'4555'},
    "Vietnamese": {flag: 'vn',cs:'4679',as:''}
};


$.each( langs, function( key, l ) {
    //console.log('length L:',Object.keys(l).length,l);
    if(Object.keys(l).length > 3)
    {
            if(key == "Europe") flag = 'eu';
            else flag = '';
            html  = '<li class="dropdown-submenu">';
            html += '  <a href="#"><span class="flag flag-'+flag+'"></span> '+key+'</a>';
            html += '  <ul class="dropdown-menu">';

            $.each( l, function( key2, l2 ) {
                console.log(key2,l2);
                if(l2.cs.length < 8)
                    l2.cs = '7108' + l.cs;
                if(l2.as.length < 8 && l2.as.length > 0)
                    l.as = '7108' + l.as;
                if(l2.as !== '')
                {
                    html += '<li class="dropdown-submenu">';
                    html += '  <a href="tel:'+l.cs+'"><span class="flag flag-'+l2.flag+'"></span> '+key2+'</a>';
                    html += '  <ul class="dropdown-menu">';
                    html += '    <li><a href="tel:'+l2.cs+'">CS: '+l2.cs.substring(4,8)+'</a></li>';
                    html += '    <li><a href="tel:'+l2.as+'">AS: '+l2.as.substring(4,8)+'</a></li>';
                    html += '  </ul>';
                    html += '</li>';
                }
                else
                {
                    html += '<li data-lang="'+l2.flag+'">';
                    html += '  <a href="tel:'+l2.cs+'"><span class="flag flag-'+l2.flag+'"></span> '+key2+'</a>';
                    html += '</li>';
                }


            });

            $('#btb_lang_list').append(html);
    }
    else
    {
        if(l.cs.length < 8)
            l.cs = '7108' + l.cs;
        if(l.as.length < 8 && l.as.length > 0)
            l.as = '7108' + l.as;
        if(l.as !== '')
        {
            html  = '<li class="dropdown-submenu">';
            html += '  <a href="tel:'+l.cs+'"><span class="flag flag-'+l.flag+'"></span> '+key+'</a>';
            html += '  <ul class="dropdown-menu">';
            html += '    <li><a href="tel:'+l.cs+'">CS: '+l.cs.substring(4,8)+'</a></li>';
            html += '    <li><a href="tel:'+l.as+'">AS: '+l.as.substring(4,8)+'</a></li>';
            html += '  </ul>';
            html += '</li>';
        }
        else
        {
            html  = '<li data-lang="'+l.flag+'">';
            html += '  <a href="tel:'+l.cs+'"><span class="flag flag-'+l.flag+'"></span> '+key+'</a>';
            html += '</li>';
        }

        $('#btb_lang_list').append(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please shorten your code/example and indicate where you're getteng an undefined reference ?

Comment: Did you try this: `langs.Europe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your 2nd loop is trying to access a variable which it doesn't have:

`$.each( l, function( key2, l2 ) {`

within that, you try to reference `l.cs` in your `function( key2, l2 )`, but that function doesn't know what `l` is, so it returns an empty local object (and `undefined` for `l.cs`)

I'm not sure, but that's my first guess from looking at it.

Comment: thank you! I was already sure that I forgot a "2" somewhere, but was not able to find it. Now it works perfectly

Comment: So, I was wrong here. `l` is accessible, but it's the array of subcountries, so it doesn't contain a `.cs` property. @nilsK provides the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in line 81 in your fiddle.

Change

`l2.cs = '7108' + l.cs;`

to

`l2.cs = '7108' + l[key2].cs;`

`l` is your first categorie (e.g. "Europe") wich doesn't have a property named `cs`. You'll need to use the countries names to get your property.

Comment: Yep, this looks like it's the problem.

Comment: No, the problem was that it should be `l2.cs = '7108' + l2.cs;`. But thanks. You pointed out the line with the error ^^

Comment: well, okay, but `l[key2].cs` works too. glad you could solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

It works if you remove the quotes from Europe, Bulgarian, etc

Comment: This not possible because my keys have white spaces.